# Tic-Tac-Toe clear method JavaScript

Tags: html, javascript

What is wrong in my clear method:

```
function _Clear(){
for (var row = 0 ; row < tbl.rows.length; row++)
{
        for (var cell = 0 ; cell < tbl.rows[row].cells.length; cell++)
        {

        tbl.rows[row].cells[cell].childNodes[0].src = null;

        }
}   
}
```

and this is my table:

```
     tbl = document.getElementById("matrix");
```

When i click clear nothing happened why ?

more html:

```
      <body>

    <table>
        <tr>
            <td width="100pt">
                <label>Player 1:</label> <input type="radio" name="players" id="player1"checked="checked"/>
            </td>
            <td width="100pt">
                <label>Player 2:</label> <input type="radio" name="players" id="player2"/>
            </td>
        <td width="100pt">
            <input type="button" onclick="_Clear()" value="Clear"/>
        </td>
        </tr>
    </table>

    <table id="matrix" border="1">
<tr>
    <td class="cellCSS">
        <img alt="Click Here" class="imageCSS" onclick="imageClicked(this,0,0)"/>
    </td>
<td class="cellCSS">
        <img alt="Click Here" class="imageCSS" onclick="imageClicked(this,0,1)"/>
    </td>
<td class="cellCSS">
        <img alt="Click Here" class="imageCSS" onclick="imageClicked(this,0,2)"/>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="cellCSS">
        <img alt="Click Here" class="imageCSS" onclick="imageClicked(this,1,0)"/>
    </td>
<td class="cellCSS">
        <img alt="Click Here" class="imageCSS" onclick="imageClicked(this,1,1)"/>
    </td>
<td class="cellCSS">
        <img alt="Click Here" class="imageCSS" onclick="imageClicked(this,1,2)"/>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="cellCSS">
        <img alt="Click Here" class="imageCSS" onclick="imageClicked(this,2,0)"/>
    </td>
<td class="cellCSS">
        <img alt="Click Here" class="imageCSS" onclick="imageClicked(this,2,1)"/>
    </td>
<td class="cellCSS">
        <img alt="Click Here" class="imageCSS" onclick="imageClicked(this,2,2)"/>
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
```

Any idea will be great

Thanks

Comment: Can you show us where the "matrix" table is defined?

Comment: This would probably be vastly easier if you used jQuery or MooTools or some other framework.

Comment: JQuery is a library... MooTools' a framework

Comment: please don't use inline event handlers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing it has something to do with how/when you declare your `tbl` variable.

http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/wfEhM/

If I declare it within the function and leave off the `var`, it's an internally scoped variable accessible when the function is called:

```
function _Clear(){
    tbl = document.getElementById("matrix");
    for (var row = 0 ; row < tbl.rows.length; row++)
    {
        for (var cell = 0 ; cell < tbl.rows[row].cells.length; cell++)
        {
            // Note, I changed this line for testing, since I don't
            // have the images.
            alert(tbl.rows[row].cells[cell].childNodes[0].src);
        }
    }   
}
```

What I think is happening is that either, a) you're creating the `tbl` variable out of scope (within another function without the `var` keyword, for example), or b) you're creating it during page load or before the `matrix` element loads, not after, so that your `tbl` pointer doesn't point anywhere. Or maybe you're doing both of these.

Answer (score 0):

check that your `tbl` variable is ok (using alert or something).

reading your code i assumed that you want to set the `src` attribute to empty when you click on the clear button... i debbuged your code and i saw that `tbl.rows[row].cells[cell].childNodes[0]` is actually a "\n" character (return to line)..

to avoid that, use `tbl.rows[row].cells[cell].getChildren()[0]` instead

good luck!